# If $(H_λ)_{λ≥0}$ is a spectral decomposition and $π_λ$ is the orthogonal projection onto $H_λ$, then $t↦π_λ$ is increasing and right-continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space. If $(\mathcal D(A),A_i)$ is a symmetric linear operator on $H$, write $A_1\le A_2$ if $$\langle A_1x,x\rangle_H\le\langle A_2x,x\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathcal D(A)\tag1.$$ Let $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ with

1. $H_\lambda$ is a closed subspace of $H$ for all $\lambda\ge0$
2. $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ is nondecreasing and *right-continuous*, i.e. $$\bigcap_{\mu>\lambda}H_\mu=H_\lambda\tag2$$

Now, let $\pi_\lambda$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $H_\lambda$ for $\lambda\ge0$. How can we show that $$[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\pi_\lambda\tag3$$ is nondecreasing (in the sense of $(1)$) and $$[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\pi_\lambda x\tag4$$ is right-continuous for all $x\in H$ (are we even able to show that $(3)$ is right-continuous?)?

Intuitively, it seems to be trivial, but how can we prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show that for all $t\ge s$,
$$
\pi_t\pi_s=\pi_s\pi_t = \pi_{s}.
$$ We can observe that $H_s\le H_t$, which implies that 
$$
\text{Im}\ \pi_s =H_s \le H_t = \ker(1-\pi_t),
$$
and
$$
\text{Im}\ (1-\pi_t) = H_t^\perp \le H_s^\perp = \ker \pi_s.
$$ This implies $(1-\pi_t)\pi_s = \pi_s(1-\pi_t) = 0$, i.e. $\pi_t\pi_s=\pi_s\pi_t = \pi_s$.

It is a direct consequence that for $t\ge s$,
$$
\langle x,\pi_s x\rangle =\|\pi_sx\|^2=\|\pi_s\pi_tx\|^2\le \|\pi_tx\|^2 =\langle x,\pi_tx\rangle,
$$ since $\|\pi_s\|\le 1$ for every $s\ge 0$.

It remains to prove right continuity of $t\mapsto \pi_t x$ for every $x$. Let $x\in H$ and $s\ge 0$ be arbitrarily given. We can find that for $t\ge s$,
$$
f(t) =\|\pi_{t}x-\pi_s x\|^2=\langle x,\pi_{t}x-\pi_s x\rangle \ge 0
$$ is a decreasing function of $t\in[s,\infty)$. Thus there is a finite limit $\lim_{t\downarrow s}f(t)$, which implies for each and every decreasing sequence $t_n \downarrow s$,
$$
\|\pi_{t_n}x-\pi_{t_m}x\|^2 =\langle x,\pi_{t_n}x-\pi_{m} x\rangle =f(t_n)-f(t_m)\xrightarrow{n,m\to\infty} 0,
$$ i.e. $(\pi_{t_n}x)_{n\ge 1}$ forms a Cauchy sequence. If we denote $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi_{t_n}x$, then we can find that
$$
\|\pi_{t_n}x-\pi_s x\|^2=\|\pi_{t_n}x-\pi_s \pi_{t_n}x\|^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \|y-\pi_s y\|^2\ge 0.
$$ Finally, from the fact that $\pi_{t_n}x \in H_t$, $t>s$ for all sufficiently large $n$'s, we can deduce that
$$
y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi_{t_n}x \in H_t,\quad \forall t>s,
$$ hence
$$
y\in \bigcap_{t>s}H_t =H_s.
$$ This proves
$$
\|\pi_{t_n}x-\pi_s x\|^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \|y-\pi_s y\|^2=0
$$ for all decreasing sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 1}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n =s$. Since  $s$ was arbitrary, the path $t\mapsto \pi_t x$ is right continuous for every $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) What dos the notation $H_s\le H_t$ mean? (b) Are we able to show that $(3)$ is right-continuous, too? (c) Can we conclude that $\pi_tx\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}x$ and that $[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto\pi_tx$ is bounded?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (a) $H_s\le H_t$ was intended to mean that $H_s$ is a closed subspace of $H_t$. (b) Continuity of $t\mapsto \pi_t$ depends on the topology endowed on linear operators. It may not be right continuous with respect to the usual norm topology, but it is right continuous with respect to strong topology, which is equivalent to saying that for every $x$, $t\mapsto \pi_t x$ is continuous. (c) Partially true, we have that $\|\pi_t x\|\le \|x\|$ for all $t$, hence it is bounded. With this fact and similar argument that I used, we can show $\pi_{t_n} x$ is Cauchy as $t_n\uparrow\infty$.

Comment: The limit will be given by $\pi_\infty x$ where $\pi_\infty$ is the orthogonal projection onto the closure of $\cup_{t>0}H_t$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm willing to assume that $\bigcup_{\lambda\ge0}$ is dense. So, this would yield the desired claim. Actually, I would like to understand why we can integrate in the Lebesgue-Stieltjes sense with respect to $\lambda\mapsto\langle\pi_\lambda x,y\rangle_H$. I've asked a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3110151/47771) for that; maybe you can help there too.

Comment: Are we able to generalize the results to families $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\mathbb R}$? I would like to show $$\lim_{\lambda\to-\infty}\pi_\lambda x=0\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H$$ in addition. I guess we need to require $$\bigcap_{\lambda\in\mathbb R}H_\lambda=\left\{0\right\}$$ for that, right?