# Integrability with respect to a spectral measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space. If $(\mathcal D(A),A_i)$ is a symmetric linear operator on $H$, write $A_1\le A_2$ if $$\langle A_1x,x\rangle_H\le\langle A_2x,x\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathcal D(A)\tag1.$$ Let $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ with

1. $H_\lambda$ is a closed subspace of $H$ for all $\lambda\ge0$
2. $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ is nondecreasing and *right-continuous*, i.e. $$\bigcap_{\mu>\lambda}H_\mu=H_\lambda\tag2$$
3. $\bigcup_{\lambda\ge0}H_\lambda$ is dense

Now, let $\pi_\lambda$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $H_\lambda$ for $\lambda\ge0$. [We can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3109522/47771) that $$[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\pi_\lambda\tag3$$ is nondecreasing (in the sense of $(1)$) and $$[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\pi_\lambda x\tag4$$ is right-continuous for all $x\in H$.

> Let $x,y\in H$. Note that $$g(\lambda):=\langle\pi_\lambda x,y\rangle_H=\frac12\left(\langle\pi_\lambda(x+y),x+y\rangle_H-\langle\pi_\lambda x,x\rangle_H-\langle\pi_\lambda y,y\rangle_H\right)\tag5$$ for all $\lambda\ge0$. $g$ is right-continuous. Moreover, by $(5)$, $g$ is the difference of nondecreasing functions and hence of bounded variation on any bounded interval. Does that suffice to conclude that there is a unique signed measure $\mu_g$ on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$ with $$\mu((a,b])=g(b)-g(a)\;\;\;\text{for all }0\le a\le b\tag6?$$ If so, any function Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is by definiton $\mu_g$-integrable if it is integrable with respect to the variation $|\mu_g|$ of $\mu_g$. Are we able to give an explicit formula for $|\mu_g|$ such that we can give a concrete characterization of $|\mu_g|$-integrability?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your question is about functions of bounded variation on $[0,\infty)$, unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Suppose $g : [0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function that is of bounded variation on every finite interval $[0,a]$. Then you can form the function $V_g(x)$ that is the variation of $g$ on $[0,x]$. This function is defined as
$$
            V_g(x)=\sup_{\mathscr{P}}\sum_{n=1}^{N}|g(x_{n-1})-g(x_n)|
$$
where the $\sup$ is taken over all finite partitions
$$\mathscr{P}=\{0=x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots x_N=x\}.$$
This allows you decompose $g$ into the difference $h-k$ of non-decreasing functions
$$
         h(x)=\frac{1}{2}(V_g(x)+g(x)),\;\; k(x)=\frac{1}{2}(V_g(x)-g(x)).
$$
So $g=(h-k)/2$ has left- and right-hand limits at every point on $(0,\infty)$ and has a right limit at $0$.
Suppose $g$ is normalized to be continuous from the right. Then so is $V_g$, which forces $h,k$ to be continuous from the right as well. From this you can find unique positive Borel measures $\mu_h$, $\mu_k$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $h(x)=\mu_h[0,x]$, $k(x)=\mu_k[0,x]$. Automatically,
$$
       g(x)=h(x)-k(x),\;\; h(x)+k(x)=V_g(x).
$$

Comment: (a) Usually, I've seen that $h$ and $k$ are defined to be $h=\frac12(V_g+g\color{red}{-g(0)})$ and $k=\frac12(V_g-g\color{red}{+g(0)})$. Does that matter? (b) Your $\mu_h$ and $\mu_k$ should only be $\sigma$-finite (they are, by construction, even finite on any compact subset). Don't you get $\infty-\infty$ problems when you're intend to define $\mu_g:=\mu_h-\mu_k$? (c) What I really want to know is whether we can give a concrete formula for the variation $|\mu_g|$ of $\mu_g$ such that we can characterize the $\mu_g$-integrable functions.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : You specifically asked a question about a function of bounded variation on $[0,\infty)$. So that's what I addressed. The value of the function at $0$ doesn't affect whether or not you can form the desired decomposition because you are looking at satisfying $\mu(a,b]=g(b)-g(a)$.

Comment: Don't understand your comment. Don't you define $\mu_g:=\mu_h-\mu_k$? Unless $g$ or $h$ is bounded, we should run into $\infty-\infty$ problems. In any case, are we able to characterize the $\mu_g$-integrable functions (in the specific case of the question)?

Comment: Please tell me where I'm mistaken. Your $g$ is only locally (i.e. on any compact interval) of bounded variation. So, we should only be able to extend the content $(a,b]\mapsto g(b)-g(a)$ to a $\sigma$-additive function on the $\delta$-ring of bounded Borel subsets of $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Your functions are bounded because you have projections. So you have the difference of bounded functions.